# getting exception when retrieving data from database org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.0

Iam new to JPA, iam trying to create EJB 3.0 + JPA (hibernate) application. When iam persisting data into database getting below exception.

**sessionBean method:**

```
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    public void showCustDetails(){
        //System.out.println(em.getProperties());
        //EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        List customer = em.createQuery("select c from CUSTOMER c").getResultList();
        System.out.println("List Size:::"+ customer.size());
        for(Object c:customer){
            Customer customers = (Customer) c;
            System.out.println("Name ::::" + customers.getName() + "::customer id ::"+customers.getCustomer_id()+"::email::"+customers.getEmail_id()+"::address::"+customers.getAddress()+
                    ":::ph number::"+customers.getPhNumber());
        }

}
```

**Customer class(entity class)**

```
package retail.model.vo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import static javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType.BEAN;
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
//@TransactionAttribute(value=REQUIRED)

public class Customer  implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5256938732963606407L;
    private int customer_id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String email_id;
    private int phNumber;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    public int getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }

    public void setCustomer_id(int customer_id) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "addres")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Column(name = "email_add")
    public String getEmail_id() {
        return email_id;
    }

    public void setEmail_id(String email_id) {
        this.email_id = email_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "ph_number")
    public int getPhNumber() {
        return phNumber;
    }

    public void setPhNumber(int phNumber) {
        this.phNumber = phNumber;
    }

     public String validate(){
          if(name!=null && name!=""){
          System.out.println("chandan");
          return "viewCustomerDetails";
          }
          else{
          return "viewCustomerDetails";
          }
          }
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
    <persistence-unit name="RetailUnit" >
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <!-- the JNDI data source-->
        <jta-data-source>java/customer</jta-data-source>
        <properties> 
            <!-- if this is true, hibernate will print (to stdout) the SQL it executes, 
                so you can check it to ensure it's not doing anything crazy
                 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
                 <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/company;create=true" />
              <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user" />
              <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="123" /> -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <!-- since most database servers have slightly different versions of the 
                SQL, Hibernate needs you to choose a dialect so it knows the subtleties of 
                talking to that server -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <!-- this tell Hibernate to update the DDL when it starts, very useful 
                for development, dangerous in production -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: CUSTOMER is not mapped [select c from CUSTOMER c]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1376)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1317)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:436)
    at retail.ejb.service.CustomerSessionBeanImpl.showCustDetails(CustomerSessionBeanImpl.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:206)
    ... 51 more
```

Please anyone suggest on this.

**Edit Out Put**

```
INFO: Name ::::sdsdfsd::customer id ::0::email::sdsdfdsdssfd::address::sdfsdsdsdsdf:::ph number::0
INFO: Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        CUSTOMER
        (customer_id, addres, email_add, Name, ph_number) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?, ?, ?)
INFO: Hibernate: 

values
    identity_val_local()

INFO: Hibernate: 
    select
        customer0_.customer_id as customer1_0_,
        customer0_.addres as addres0_,
        customer0_.email_add as email3_0_,
        customer0_.Name as Name0_,
        customer0_.ph_number as ph5_0_ 
    from
        CUSTOMER customer0_
INFO: List Size:::1
INFO: Name ::::sdsdfsd::customer id ::1::email::sdsdfdsdssfd::address::sdfsdsdsdsdf:::ph number::0
```

[image]

Comment: did you figure out your issue from yesterday?  What was the problem?

Comment: @KevinBowersox yes . But it your answer doesnot help me.But i fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the entity must be spelled exactly as defined by the class name, independent of the table mapping, in your case it would be `Customer`.

To be exact, the `String` corresponds to the output of `myEntity.getClass().getSimpleName();`

EDIT: JPQL != SQL

More often than not you will not get the same results (if any) using the same JPQL query with an SQL editor and vice versa. While SQL uses table identifiers, JPQL uses entities, corresponding to classes.

Comment: thanks alot . iam able to retrieve the data now, but when i run the same query on eclipse sql editor, iam getting zero rows. But in code iam able to get the data. Its surprising me.

Comment: also i try to run the query on derby command tool. there also i got zero rows :(

Comment: @developer you're welcome. The behaviour is to be expected, please see the edit.

Comment: is that not inserting into database. Please can you explain clearly

Comment: @developer - I'm not sure I understand the last question. What is not inserting? I thought you were selecting/querying.

Comment: when i excute the code, on console its showing as inserting data and retrieveing data, but when i check in table by run the query from druby tool, iam getting 0 rows . I attached the screenshot please chcek.

Comment: please can you help on the above issue

Comment: @developer - I would be glad to, but i still dont understand what the issue is, sorry - is it that the query from the derby console does not return records? This could have many reasons and I am not sure what it is. But the one idea I have - change the console query to `select * from customer` - I think customer.customer is not correct.

Comment: your are absolutely correct. My half knowledge move me into unnecessary trouble. query which i written is wrong. Thanks Kostja